# What is the Entity Key for in the Datastore Viewer?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am new to Google App Engine, Python and NoSQL.

While browsing the Datastore Viewer I noticed that there is a key labelled "Key" in the list view, and "Entity Key" in the single entity edit view, which is generated automatically.

What is it for? Should I use this to identify my entities? Or should I just ignore it? Is it an internal key used by App Engine?

Any light shed on this would be much appreciated!

Thanks

UPDATE:

Here is a screenshot of what is confusing me: http://snag.gy/J7ISd.jpg

From left to right in the table there is "Key" (the one that I am asking about), "Write Ops", "ID", "Key Name". My question is, what is "Key" used for?

UPDATE 2:

Tim Hoffman answered my question in the comment. The "Key" column is the url safe version of the whole key.

So to sum up, the key of an entity is composed of either a numeric ID or a string key, AND each entity also has a url safe version that can be passed around the URLs, that is automatically generated.

Comment: You need to read the docs, understanding what the key is, how it's used is fundamental to appengine - https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entities

Comment: I did read the docs, and from what I understand the key is composed of either a numeric id, or a string. In the datastore viewer I see 2 types of strings. See screenshot: [link](http://snag.gy/J7ISd.jpg)

Comment: You specifically asked "What is it for? Should I use this to identify my entities? Or should I just ignore it? Is it an internal key used by App Engine?"   - all of this is explained in the docs.

Comment: How is it confusing, the datastore viewer is just breaking the key up into it's constituent parts for your convenience.  If you supply a string for the name/id it's stored as a string. If the system generates the id it's an int.  This is documented.  And there are note two types of string.  The value in the Key column is the URL safe version of the whole key.

Comment: That very last sentence answered my question: "The value in the Key column is the URL safe version of the whole key.". Thank you!

Comment: And by the way, it was confusing. There are 3 unique strings/id that you can use to identify an entity, but the doc mentions 2 only.

Comment: I suppose we will disagree on that point - https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities  covers all the presentation forms of the Key.  What you assume is 3 unique strings/id are only a part of the key.  The id/name part can be a string or an int, but that is only part of the key.  The urlsafe form is the complete key encoded so that it can be passed around in URLs.  There is only the Key (constructed of parts) and string form presentation.

Comment: It's not correct that "each entity also has a url safe version [of the key] that is automatically generated". The url-safe version of the key is created when needed by application code, in this case by the Admin Viewer code.

Comment: That makes sense now. If you post an answer with this information in it I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datastore entities are [represented by their unique key](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entities). As the docs state, each entity in the Datastore has a key that uniquely identifies it. The key consists of the following components:

- The kind of the entity, which categorizes it for the purpose of Datastore queries
- An identifier for the individual entity, which can be either
  a key name string
  an integer numeric ID
- An optional ancestor path locating the entity within the Datastore hierarchy

Comment: In your second bullet point you mention a key name and an ID. I wonder what the first column (Key) is on my screenshot.